# saving parentheses or quotations into sql in vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

i have a save command on  my vb project. the problem is that it won't save texts with " ' " or parentheses. i think it has something to do with the sql command.. here is my code for saving as well as update

saving

```
  Dim myAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
            Dim myDatatable As New DataTable
            Dim command As New MySqlCommand
            Dim add As String

            add = "INSERT INTO tracker.recordtracker (Action_Taken,Marginal_Note,Remarks,Type_of_Document,Referred_Date,Items,Received_From,Received_Date,Referred_To,recdate,refdate)values('" + acttaken.Text + "','" + margnote.Text + "','" + remarks.Text + "','" + doctype.Text + "','" + rfrldatelbl.Text + "','" + itemtbx.Text + "','" + rfromtbx.Text + "','" + rcvdate.Text + "','" + reftotbx.Text + "' ,'" + rdate.Text + "',@refdate)"
            command = New MySqlCommand(add, connection)
            refdate.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"


            myAdapter.SelectCommand = command
            myAdapter.Fill(myDatatable)
            MsgBox("Data has been successfully added.")
            clearfield()
            loaddatabase()

            connection.Close()
            connection.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

for update

```
Try
                connection.Open()
                rcvdate.Text = rdate.Text
                If refdate.Checked = False Then
                    rfrldatelbl.Text = "____-__-__"
                Else
                    refdate.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
                    rfrldatelbl.Text = refdate.Text + " " + TimeOfDay
                End If

                Dim query As String
                query = "update tracker.recordtracker set Action_Taken='" & acttaken.Text & "', Marginal_Note='" & margnote.Text & "', Remarks='" & remarks.Text & "',Type_of_Document='" & doctype.Text & "', Items = '" & itemtbx.Text & "', Referred_To='" & reftotbx.Text & "', Referred_Date='" & rfrldatelbl.Text & "',recdate='" & rdate.Text & "',refdate='" & refdate.Text & "' where id = '" & ID.Text & "'"

                utos = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
                reader = utos.ExecuteReader

                MsgBox("Data has been changed.")
                connection.Close()
                loaddatabase()

                connection.Close()
                connection.Dispose()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
```

Comment: if you want to use a quote in a sql string you need to do '' or "" (double single quote or double double quote to display ' and " respectively

Comment: While what @JeremyC. says is true - please consider using parameterised queries.  You are at a lot of risk from SQL Injection if you just manually escape the quotes...

Comment: very true, I should have added that in my comment @MattFellows, mrkdenz let's say in the ID.text someone sets: 1'';DROP TABLE tracker.recordtracker; it might result into your table being dropped after the update

Answer (score 3):

You've appended to a string that forms an SQL query.  You will want to read up on `SQL injection` to see why that is a terrible idea. But basically it would allow anyone who has access to submitting those values you append to your string, control over you database.  You will probably want to do something like:

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO foo (baz) VALUES (@Baz)"

Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string here"), _
    cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Baz", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Baz
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

to get around your issue.

Answer (score 0):

From [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)

> A string is a sequence of bytes or characters, enclosed within either
>   single quote (“'”) or double quote (“"”)

So `'` is reserved character.
You need use escape sequences `\'` if you want use it in the content of the string.

But as @Matt Fellows mentioned in his answer better practice for saving string values in the database will be `SqlParameters`
With `SqlParameter` you do not need to use escape sequences, string will be save just as it is(based on the type of the column)

```vb
Dim param As New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName="@text",
                                    .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
                                    .Value = "Your 'Name' in quotes"}
```